# Lambda expression reaching scope

Tags: c++, lambda

In my Object-Oriented-Programming class at school, we were introduced to *Lambda expressions* in C++, and the professor explicitly said that the reaching scope for capturing variables inside the lambda expression is **only** the inner-most encapsulating scope.

My conclusion, considering the lecture, is that the code below shouldn't have worked, since variables `b` and `c` are defined outside the inner-most encapsulation scope of lambda's own scope. Unfortunately, it does work.

I had tried compiling the code with *g++* and *clang*, and both produced the *correct?* result.

My question is whether this is *undefined behaviour*, or the compilers are trying to do something they do with it, or perhaps we were taught incorrectly?

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    {
        int b = 10;
        {
            int c = 15;
            {
                int a = 10;
                auto f = [&]()
                {
                    std::cout << a << b << c;
                };
                f();
                std::cout << a;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, while practicing Lambda expressions with assistant professor, he told us to try and compile the following `.cpp` file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int x = 7;
  std::function<void()> foo;
  {
    int z = 19;
    foo = [x, z]() mutable
    {
      x = 5;
      std::cout << x << " " << z << std::endl;
    };
  }
  foo();
  std::cout << x;
  return 0;
}
```

After it compiled, he stated that this shouldn't happen, but compilers still do it, and that variable `x` shouldn't be reachable by lambda expression.

Comment: I've never studied this in detail, but it looks like your professor was wrong.  Have you tried running this through more than one compiler?  Plenty to choose from at Godbolt.  I wouldn't expect anything to change though.

Comment: b and c are defined outside, but they do exist and are reachable in the inner-most encapsulating scope as well. Contrary to the outer-most a. So perhaps this is just a matter of bad wording?

Comment: Beware of auto-capturing by reference. You can really shoot yourself in the foot with that.

Comment: Perhaps he meant that you can only access the inner-most `a` variable here, but that seems obvious since, how would you refer to the outer one?

Comment: @paddy Why? I can't think of anything outright bad unless you call the lambda in different scope or mark it as `mutable`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I tried something there with the another definition of a, you can ignore that, that is not the question. What he said is I shouldn't be able to capture the variables a(in scope of main),b,c..

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, I runned it through 4-5 compilers and all of them compiled and have correct results.

Comment: To be precise: the behaviour you see in the code is well defined and as expected. The explanation done by your professor is vague, but not necessarily wrong (as I stated in my previous comment).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen When constructing and storing lambdas for later use, the practice of always lazily using reference-capture can lead to not really thinking about what variables are required in the lambda, their scope, or the lifetime of the lambda. This can be a problem in more complex projects, especially when the code controlling the creation of the lambda changes in some way as to affect the lifetime of any variables that might be auto-captured.

Comment: Your professor is correct.  Your conclusion is incorrect.

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) says _"Only lambda-expressions defined at block scope or in a default member initializer may have a capture-default or captures without initializers. For such lambda-expression, the reaching scope is defined as the set of enclosing scopes up to and including the innermost enclosing function (and its parameters). This includes nested block scopes and the scopes of enclosing lambdas if this lambda is nested."_

Comment: @Eljay, yeah I'm pretty sure my conclusion was correct, going over lambdas on lab practice, assistant professor showed that this works and stated "compiler does something, but it shouldn't be working".

Comment: Edited the question with example from lab practice.

Comment: There is no way for the inner scope lambda to capture the outer scope `a`.  It can **only** capture the inner scope `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example code appears valid, at least for C++17 (and I'd guess others, but 17 is the standard I happen to have on hand). Section 8.1.5.2 on lambda captures says (emphasis mine):

> A lambda-expression whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope (6.3.3) is a local lambda expression; any
> other lambda-expression shall not have a capture-default or simple-capture in its lambda-introducer. **The
> reaching scope of a local lambda expression is the set of enclosing scopes up to and including the innermost
> enclosing function and its parameters.** [ Note: This reaching scope includes any intervening lambda-expressions.
> — end note ]

So it seems like the compilers are behaving as expected per the standard